# Kafka Producer Retry and Failed record handling

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My requirement as follows -

apart from broker metadata related error -I  try to simulate a **RecordTooLargeException**  while sending the message to the Kafka Topic.

For the producer configuration I add **acks: all  and retries: 5**
Also I use addCallback method to send the message.

I received org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 2000103 bytes when serialized which is larger than 1048576, which is the value of the max.request.size configuration.

but I did not notice any retry ( 5 times ) in the log.

My requirement is retry 5 times , then marked the record as permanent failure and send back to the call back handler - for further reprocess the failed record( ex. send to DLT or DB)

How can I achieve this kind of retry and handling?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. As per theory KAFKA Producer API doesn't retry on **RecordTooLargeException**, that means it is a non-retriable exception. If you still want to break this and retry irrespectively, then you can catch that Exception string through the Search String when error returned from the broker and retry from the catch block as many as times you want.

Comment: In consumer case - we provide either non retriable or retriable exceptions with Back off configuration.  In producer How Kafka will automatically identifies - the exception retriable or non retriable ?

Comment: It is internal to the KAFKA and you can refer https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/errors/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

> KafkaProducer has two types of errors. Retriable errors are those that can be resolved by sending the message again. For example, a connection error can be resolved because the connection may get reestablished. A “not leader for partition” error can be resolved when a new leader is elected for the partition and the client metadata is refreshed. KafkaProducer can be configured to retry those errors automatically, so the application code will get retriable exceptions only when the number of retries was exhausted and the error was not resolved. Some errors will not be resolved by retrying — for example, “Message size too large.” In those cases, KafkaProducer will not attempt a retry and will return the exception immediately.
> -- *Kafka: The Definitive Guide 2nd Edition, Chapter 3*

`RecordTooLargeException` is a non-retriable exception, retrying makes no sense if the max.request.size configuration does not change. Therefore, Kafka producer will not attempt a retry and will return the exception immediately. The callback handler will be triggered for further reprocess.